# (Problem building Android in version Unity 2018.3.0f2

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, build.gradle, unity-editor

I updated the unity to version 2018.3.0f2 . I'm having trouble building Android APK in the new version. In version 2018.3.0f2 building Android APK display the following error. There was no problem in the previous version of 2018.2.20. This problem exists in the new project in gradle mode. I did not find any solution. Please help me to fix this problem. this problem there is both JDK embedded and jdk1.8.0_191. How to fix this problem?

**Error in JDK Embedded(Open JDK 1.8.0_152):**

```
     CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
 C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.6.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

 stderr[

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':lintVitalRelease'.
 > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':lintClassPath'.
    > Could not find kotlin-compiler.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:26.2.0).
      Searched in the following locations:
          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/26.2.0/kotlin-compiler-26.2.0.jar

 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

 BUILD FAILED in 48s
 ]
 stdout[
 :checkReleaseClasspath UP-TO-DATE
 :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
 :preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
 :compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
 :compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
 :checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
 :generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
 :prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
 :mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
 :generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
 :generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
 :mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
 :createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
 :processReleaseManifest
 :splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease UP-TO-DATE
 :processReleaseResources
 :generateReleaseSources
 :javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
 :compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
 :compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
 :compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
 :lintVitalRelease FAILED
 16 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 13 up-to-date
 ]
 exit code: 1
 UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
 Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
 UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
 UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

**Error in JDK1.8.0_191:**

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
 C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.6.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

 stderr[

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':lintVitalRelease'.
 > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':lintClassPath'.
    > Could not find kotlin-compiler.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:26.2.0).
      Searched in the following locations:
          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/26.2.0/kotlin-compiler-26.2.0.jar

 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

 BUILD FAILED in 31s
 ]
 stdout[
 :checkReleaseClasspath UP-TO-DATE
 :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
 :preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
 :compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
 :compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
 :checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
 :generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
 :prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
 :mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
 :generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
 :generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
 :mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
 :createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
 :processReleaseManifest
 :splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease UP-TO-DATE
 :processReleaseResources
 :generateReleaseSources
 :javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
 :compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
 :compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
 :compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
 :lintVitalRelease FAILED
 16 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 13 up-to-date
 ]
 exit code: 1
 UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
 Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
 UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
 UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

[image: Unity Error]
[image: Console Log Embedded JDK]
[image: Console Log JDK1.8.191]
[image: Console Log 2]
[image: Console Log 3]

---

---

**----------------------------------------**

**I Solved My Problem**

**My Windows needed the Kotlin Compiler.
After installing the Kotlin Compiler from the link below:**

**[Download Kotlin Compiler](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.3.11)**

**Then the problem was solved using the installation guide in the link below:**

**[Help Install Compiler](https://turreta.com/2017/05/22/kotlin-compile-and-run-from-windows-command-line/)**

**It worked for me. I hope it has been helpful. Maybe help others.**

Comment: Did you try to build the project with Internal Build System and see the result?

Comment: @user1579019 no, i use gradle. Internal System worked right. but i use facebook sdk and google sdk and firebase. they need build gradle not build in Internal System.

Answer (score 0):

In manifest file delete all activities that are not used and also those that create the error. see console where the errors occur in a specific line.